# Проблемы со спрайтами: падение FPS

Tags: visual-studio, c++, opengl

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема: есть динамическая сцена (точка обзора меняется с течением времени), я вывожу некоторое количество спрайтов (полупрозрачные с текстурой). Если они все находятся на достаточно близком расстоянии друг от друга (например, по цепочке с очень малым шагом) и я приближаюсь к какому-либо из них (в частности к первому), то сильно падает FPS, получается эффект, что я смотрю на сену почти через все спрайты сразу. Может быть, тут подходит термин множественное смешивание? Как обойти это место? Я во время отрисовки отключаю тест глубины. Если его оставить включенным, то FPS падать перестает, но вывод всего этого дела становится некорректным. Объекты в сене я сортирую.

Вот так вычисляю координат спрайта:

```
double ModelViewMatrix[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ModelViewMatrix);
// Построим вектора вверх и вправо

Right.x = (float)ModelViewMatrix[0];
Right.y = (float)ModelViewMatrix[4];
Right.z = (float)ModelViewMatrix[8];

Up.x = (float)ModelViewMatrix[1];
Up.y = (float)ModelViewMatrix[5];
Up.z = (float)ModelViewMatrix[9];
// Вычислим четыре координаты спрайта

Coo[0].x = (-Right.x-Up.x); 
Coo[0].y = (-Right.y-Up.y); 
Coo[0].z = (-Right.z-Up.z);

Coo[1].x = (Right.x-Up.x);
Coo[1].y = (Right.y-Up.y);
Coo[1].z = (Right.z-Up.z);

Coo[2].x = (Right.x+Up.x); 
Coo[2].y = (Right.y+Up.y);
Coo[2].z = (Right.z+Up.z);

Coo[3].x = (-Right.x+Up.x);
Coo[3].y = (-Right.y+Up.y);
Coo[3].z = (-Right.z+Up.z);
```

Так рисую сам спрайт:

```
void sprit(float x, float y, float z, float Size, float r, float g, float b, float bind){
forsprit();
glColor4ub(r,g,b,bind);
glTranslatef(x,y,z); 
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(Size*Coo[0].x,Size*Coo[0].y, Size*Coo[0].z);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex3f(Size*Coo[1].x,Size*Coo[1].y, Size*Coo[1].z);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(Size*Coo[2].x,Size*Coo[2].y, Size*Coo[2].z);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(Size*Coo[3].x,Size*Coo[3].y, Size*Coo[3].z);
glEnd();    
glTranslatef(-x,-y,-z); }
```

ну и собственно рисование в общем виде

```
 void star(float x, float y, float z, float Size, float r, float g, float b, int     num)
 {
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);        
  glEnable(GL_BLEND);                                   
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
sprit(x,y,z,Size, r*255,g*255,b*255,255);   
sprit(x,y,z,Size*0.65, 255,255,255,255);    
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вывод в вашем случае может быть некорректным из-за неверной настройки глубины, либо неправильном порядке отрисовки прозрачных/полупрозрачных обьектов...

1. Увеличьте расстояния между спрайтами.
2. Измените блок инициализации OpenGL.

   ```
   gluPerspective( 45.0f, (GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,(цифра здесь меньше расстояния между спрайтами) , 100.0f );
   ```

Comment: цифра в перспектив у меня больше 1 т.е. 1600/900 а расстояния между спрайтами много меньше 1 проблема точно не в этом. Вывод у меня корректный с отключенным буфером глубины!, то есть порядок отрисовки верный тут точно проблем нет некорректность вывода спрайтов заключается в том что они то прозрачные то  нет, то есть проскакивает квадратная каёмка, то есть каёмка прозрачная она показывает задний план но перекрашивает спрайт который находится прямо за ним и эти глюки рандомны (подчеркиваю что это при ВКЛЮЧЕННОМ тесте глубины)(продолжение следует)

Comment: продолжение - поясните пожалуйста что за настройки глубины? вы имеете ввиду перспективу? я ее задаю вот так
 gluPerspective (45.0f, (GLfloat)(width)/(GLfloat)(height), 1.0f, 22000); 
Увеличение расстояния между спрайтами не возможно ибо их положение есть результат работы программы. Задача: моделирование взаимодействия тел в космосе, спрайты отвечают непосредственно за солнца. Кстати опыт показывает что не обязательно скопление спрайтов фпс падает если один из спрайтов на весь экран и я смотрю через него на сцену

Comment: есть аналогичная ситуация, если кто-то проходит (пролетает) сквозь облако дыма. (для облегчения понимания сути проблемы)
кстати говоря, обойти ситуацию, когда один из спрайтов на весь экран легко решается, просто запретить такое близкое приближение но тем не менее проблема с цепочкой так не решить ибо там так близко приближаться не приходится чтоб падало fps (загрузка ЦП при это 3-9%)